# Win32_IP4RouteTable Class Failure

Tags: windows-7, windows, python

I've written a Python script which accesses the `Win32_IP4RouteTable` with the following:

```
import wmi
import socket

ip = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
rt = wmi.WMI().Win32_IP4RouteTable(Destination = ip)
```

The issue is that the last line fails on one computer in the office.  The owner of this computer claims that he hasn't edited anything related to this except to alter the connection priority.  The traceback he receives is below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\wmi.py", line 1147, in __getattr__
    return getattr (self._namespace, attribute)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 522, in
__getattr__
    raise AttributeError("%s.%s" % (self._username_, attr))
AttributeError: winmgmts:.Win32_IP4RouteTable
```

So my question is what could have happened which would remove python's ability to reference this class?  Thanks in advance

The computer is Windows 7 64-bit

EDIT:

I noticed a bit later that another few lines also fail:

```
from win32com.client import GetObject
WMI = GetObject('winmgmts:')
processes = WMI.InstancesOf('Win32_Process')  #Failure here
```

Comment: On the affected computer, if you type in `wmic path win32_IP4RouteTable get Destination` do you get results or an error? If an error, follow Katy's tutorial on fixing WMI corruption and see if that solves your issue. http://katyscode.wordpress.com/2007/02/03/tutorial-how-to-fix-wmi-corruption/ WMI, being a service, can be corrupt by crashes and other issues. Hopefully the steps in the tutorial can assist you without having to reinstall.

Comment: @JSanchez, that got actual output, I assume this means the problem is in Python?

Comment: May be an issue with Python. For the `ip` variable, do you have a value in there? Not too well-versed (e.g. not at all) in Python. But I'm curious now...hopefully, someone savvier than I can assist you with that one. :-(

Comment: I'll let the question here for a while, and if I don't hear anything for a bit I'll assume it's python related and move it to Stack Overflow.  But yes, the ```ip``` variable does have the correct value in it.  I also think the problem is deeper because another C-class failed as well (this time when accessing the process list)

Comment: Wrote a small (well, not too small, since I couldn't paste it here) VBScript that sort of does what your script does (well, the querying WMI part) and was wondering if you wouldn't mind trying on the affected computer and seeing if you get something. If not, then definitely a WMI issue. If yes, then a Python->WMI issue?

Comment: @JSanchez, sure, is it up on the web somewhere?  I have no idea how to run VBScripts though

Comment: I hope I set the access rights correctly: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3C1d6NV_8-6TmdTU3JvaHY1bFE/edit?usp=sharing To execute the script, from a command prompt, type in `cscript /nologo wmi_test.vbs` and you should see the IP address of the computer twice

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12870/discussion-between-wnnmaw-and-jsanchez)